# Как преобразовать бинарную строку в словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую `Python 3`. Ко мне приходит `json` в таком формате:

```
b'{\n    "begindate": "2016-11-22", \n    "enddate": "2016-11-22", \n    "guids": ["6593062E-9030-B2BC-E63A-25FBB4723ECC", \n              "5A9F8478-6673-428A-8E90-3AC4CD764543", \n              "D8243BA1-0847-48BE-9619-336CB3B3C70C"]\n}'
```

При попытке сделать `json.loads()` возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Если сделать `str()`, то строка превратится в такое:

```
'b\'{\\n    "begindate": "2016-11-22", \\n    "enddate": "2016-11-22", \\n    "guids": ["6593062E-9030-B2BC-E63A-25FBB4723ECC", \\n              "5A9F8478-6673-428A-8E90-3AC4CD764543", \\n              "D8243BA1-0847-48BE-9619-336CB3B3C70C"]\\n}\''
```

Распарсить это еще тяжелее. Что делать ?

Comment: Неанглийских символов в жсоне точно не будет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как вам `json` пришел в виде байтовой строки, то для начала необходимо перевести полученное сообщение в строку при помощи метода `decode`, так вы получите строку. Далее эту строку преобразуете в `json` при помощи метода `loads`.

Вот так:

```
s = b'{"key": "value"}' # ваша строка
json.loads(s.decode())
```